# Webpack: How to separate UI from business logic in Electron app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, vue.js, electron

I'm developing a desktop app on Electron + Vue 2 + Webpack 2 + Bootstrap 3. Currently, all JS code is bundled by webpack and is included in the HTML as a single file.

**index.html**

```
<body>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
```

Everything working OK, but...

The main flaw is that the `bundle.js` size is too big. Although, I've used Webpack CommonsChunkPlugin to split bundle.js into `app.js` (my code) and vendor.js (third-party libs) I still have a feeling that something is wrong. In Electron there is **no need to bundle everything together** because files won't be transferred via network. But in the other side I need Webpack to compile Vue templates. So, I would like to find a way to separate UI from business logic:

```
<body>
    <!-- UI: views, controllers, etc / bundled by webpack -->
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor.js"></script>
    <!-- business logic : models, services, DAO etc / NOT bundled by webpack -->
    <script src="logic.js"></script>
</body>
```

The problem is that I don't understand how to call business logic/service (defined in logic.js) from Vue template (defined in app.js). Whaterver I'm trying webpack always replace `require()`for `logic.js` with this:

```
var test = __webpack_require__(!(function webpackMissingModule() { var e = new Error("Cannot find module \"so many time wasted here\""); e.code = 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'; throw e; }()));
```

Can someone please provide a small example? Or link to boilerplate app?

P.S. This is my first Electron app. Maybe I'm trying to do something wrong? Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

---

**UPD:** Ok, thanks to [this thread](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/839) I've solved the problem.

TL;DR:

> [externals](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#externals)
>
> Indicates dependencies that should not be bundled by webPack but
>   instead remain requested by the resulting bundle.

define:

```
externals: [
    "some_module"
],
```

and use:

```
var someMethod = require('some_module');
console.log(someMethod());
```

Comment: But it seems `externals` won't be compiled. You can try [multiple entries](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-filename) to do something like, outputing compiled files one by one with their source file names, from `src/` to `build/`.

Comment: @PanJunjie潘俊杰       I don't need to compile/transpile `externals` - Electron supports ES6. Also, there is no need to include `logic.js` to HTML page.